# Google Maps V3 within a jQuery UI dialog for IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problems visualizing my google map within a jquery dialog. The problem is present only on ie 7 and ie 8, furthermore ie7 doesn't even show the map, ie8 shows it once and when you try to see it again, the map is misplaced.

Here is the scenario. I have a link which when precessed would show a dialog. The content of the dialog is loaded via ajax. The loaded page contains some other stuff apart from the map itself. In ie7 i don't see the page at all, i8 shows it correctly the first time around. When you close the dialog and open it again the map would no longer be visible. [image]

The issue(s) is not present on all real browsers and ie9,but i found something strange. When the dialog is opened for the second time and I have dev tools open ( the developer plugin for IE) when I close it, or minimize the dev tools panel , the map is somehow refreshed and gets displayed correctly. Any idea what event my that be triggering. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hey Peter...more of a tech question than anything, but the javascript you've got to initialise the map in the dialog: is it contained in the main page, or are you relying on the called AJAX page to run the javascript and containing it in that page instead?

Comment: The map itself is created within the Ajax page. I cannot actually move the map creation as the code is used in various places and I am reusing bits of it on few places. I read this : [link] (http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/google-maps-in-jquery-ui-dialog/), it's similar but not applicable to my case as I actually donnot have access to the map instance while the dialog is being created. I mean the parent creates the dialog and the injected page within a $(document).ready event creates the google.Map instance.

Answer (score 2):

Call the initialise function after dialog opens. For example, onfocus of a button or textbox.

```
onfocus="initialise();";
```

it works for me.... even in IE

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure gmaps v3 doesn't support IE7, the IE8 problem is kinda hard to assist you with without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript API V3 does support IE7+ (Source: [Which web browsers does the Google Maps JS API support?](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#browsersupport)) but I've seen issues when combining it with jQuery, sometimes they kinda collide on some object's property and mess up. Maybe you could cut this down to the simplest code possible and report it on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)?